# Where should drupal_set_title() be called when trying to override a node's title?

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to override a node page's title using `drupal_set_title(...)` but am a little unsure of where I should be calling this method.

Currently I'm calling it in `theme_preprocess_page(...)` but it seems to be being overridden after I've overridden it and is being changed back to just the node's title.

I'm presuming there's another hook I can use to call `drupal_set_title(...)` to prevent my custom title from being overridden? Or maybe there's another way around this particular problem?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>try `drupal_set_title()` inside `theme_preprocess_node()`</del>

hmm, doesn't work.

You can set `$vars['head_title']` inside `theme_preprocess_node()`, this will definitely work.

`drupal_set_title()` will work if placed inside `node.tpl.php`

Comment: Actually, calling drupal_set_title() inside theme_preprocess_node() did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the page title in the browser tab/bar being different from the node title, check out the Page Title module.

http://drupal.org/project/page_title

Answer (score 0):

Try this if none of the above has worked:

```
function YOUR-THEME_process_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add') {
    switch(arg(2)) {
      case 'YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE':
       $variables['title'] = t('New Record');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.